# My app isn't recognized anymore as the app (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm building an iPhone app in Xcode. I used to archive the app to submit it to iTunesConnect so I was able to use TestFlight. But now when I archive the app (is does so successfully), the Archive Organizer puts my app at the 'Other Versions' tab instead of the tab of the app itself.

I've checked the Bundle ID, and it's still the same as it says on iTunesConnect. I also use 'Automatically manage signing', which are the correct settings as well.

Where should I check next for what might've gone wrong?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark: did you change the clock on your machine?

Comment: @mattliu no I didn't